# Finding top most used HIVE Tables

Tags: hive, data-warehouse

We are using HIVE extensively in our data warehouse solution. Many scheduled jobs and adhoc queries are accessing these. How can I find which HIVE tables are most popular in my company.

So that I could take some action to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which distribution of Hadoop you're running Hive on, but if it is Cloudera, you can have a look at Cloudera Navigator Optimizer:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/11/introducing-cloudera-navigator-optimizer-for-optimal-sql-workload-efficiency-on-apache-hadoop/

Profile SQL workloads to get visibility across multiple dimensions including:

- A ‘dashboard’ view: of the SQL operations, table usage, and query
  usage patterns
- A popular view: of the most frequently used tables,
  queries, and column patterns
- A deep-dive view: of each table and
  query’s main characteristics, patterns, and complexities
- A highlights
  view: of the major insights drawn from analyzing the entire workload

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/navopt/topics/EvaluatingHiveImpalaWorkloads.html

> Use Case: Evaluate Query Sets by CPU Time, Memory Usage, and File
>   System Reads/Writes

Even without Cloudera Navigator Optimizer, and with just Cloudera Navigator, I guess you could get similar data from Navigator's Solr backend database.

I am not aware of any other products that offer similar functionality (I am not affiliated with Cloudera, but use their products as a client).